# Select node based on attribute value LINQ to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I want to select xml node based on attribute. I'm very new to how linq to xml works, and can't write proper query. How can I fix it?

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Enable0" value="true" />
    <!-- dumb comment -->
    <add key="Enable1" value="false" />
    <!-- dumb comment1-->
    <add key="Enable2" value="true" />
    <add key="Enable3" value="false" />
    <!-- dumb comment2 -->
    <add key="Enable4" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <asdf>
    <a key="b"></a>
    <a key="c"></a>
    <a key="d"></a>
  </asdf>
</configuration>
```

My attempt:

```
        private string GetAttribute(string name)
    { 

        //???
        var query = from node in deafultElement.Elements("add")
                    where node.Attribute("key").Value == name
                    select node.Attribute("value").value;

        return query.toString();
        //currently returns "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]"
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills I'll edit and add some sample xml I use for tests, but what more code do you want? I'm not sure which parts of code would be relevant for this question.

Comment: You do a `select .Value` which will be a string, not a Node/Element.

Comment: @mjwills then I can simply delete all code and show only that broken query. Would that be good option?

Comment: Don't use Value : (string)node.Attribute("key") & (string)node.Attribute("value") If the object doesn't exist you will get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use linq methods' syntax to reach the same result.

```
string value = defaultElement.Elements("add")
            .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Attribute("key").Value == name)
            .Attribute("value").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var query = (from node in deafultElement.Elements("add")
      where node.Attribute("key").Value == name
      select node.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
  return query
```